# Keeping dropdown in wordpress open

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using wp-bootstrap-navwalker in wordpress and trying to design the main menue in a way that by clicking on the options in the menue, when it drops down, keep it open while navigating to sublinks. However, when i click on sublinks the dropdown part of the menue closes. How can I prevent it disapears/close after navigating to another page since I want to keep the drop down part open in the new page. I am trying to have the same menu like this site:
http://www.serneke.se/.

this is my code :

## Menu code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header" >
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

             <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav pull-right',
                'fallback_cb'       =>    `enter code here`'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        ?>

        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
========================================================
(function($){ 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(){
        $(".dropdown-toggle").removeAttr('data-toggle');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

=========================================================
I believe my code disables dropdown menue to close if one clicks on it again, still when i click on sublink, dropdown closes anyway. Please guide me

Comment: can you share your website link please?

Comment: Hi Raj, I have my site local on my computer